# bad accent position

Tags: positioning, accents, cyrillic

Can anybody tell me how to get the right position of grave accent (or accents at all) above Cyrillic letters?

with this

```
|| \textbf{\mbox{сп\`{о}р-ен}, -ни} \textit{прил.\,м.} || \textbf{спор\`{я}} \textit{гл.}
```

I'm getting

[image]

I'm using polyglossia package, Linux Libertine font and TeXworks. with Latin letters everything works well

EDIT

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle},Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{czech}
\setotherlanguage{bulgarian}

\begin{document}

\textbulgarian{
|| \textbf{\mbox{сп\`{о}р-ен}, -ни} \textit{прил.\,м.} || \textbf{спор\`{я}} \textit{гл.} 
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think people would appreciate a filly compilable minimal example.

Comment: Seems like a font problem; with other fonts it shows correctly.

Comment: Your example doesn't compile at all for me because the font does not support Cyrillic.

Comment: `Linux Libertine O` works. That is, it compiles. The accents are misplaced, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow up the comments (and from curiosity), here's the same text in Noto Serif:

[image: Noto Serif]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Noto Serif}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{czech}
\setotherlanguage{bulgarian}

\begin{document}

\textbulgarian{
|| \textbf{\mbox{сп\`{о}р-ен}, -ни} \textit{прил.\,м.} || \textbf{спор\`{я}} \textit{гл.}
}
\end{document}
```